# Swift - Create post- and prefix operator?

Tags: swift, operators

In math it is common to write the amount of a number x as |x|. I would like to adopt a similar method to my code. My try on this looks like this:

```
prefix operator |
postfix operator |

extension Int {
    lazy var absolute = false
    static prefix func | (right: Int) -> Int {
        assert(right.absolute, "Missed closing absolute value bar.")
        right.absolute = false
        if right < 0 {
            return -value
        }
        return value
    }
    static postfix func | (left: Int) -> Int {
        assert(!left.absolute, "Missed opening absolute value bar.")
        left.absolute = true
        return left
    }
}
```

(I think this code won't compile as you cannot add stored properties in extensions as far as I know. It is only there to demonstrate my attempt. I added this functionality to my custom types.)

Despite the fact that this feels like a rather bad solution to me, another problem with this code is, that it won't throw any error, if I forget the opening bar. The assert will only break the running program whenever I call another amount function after forgetting the opening bar in the previous amount function call.

Let me know if you have a better solution! 
Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking to find the absolute value of a number? Or do you have to implement the operator?

Comment: Whenever I type |x| into my code I want to get the absolute value of x. So it is about the operator layout rather than about the amount function.

Comment: yea my question is why do you want to implement an operator for something that Swift already gives you? Beauty? If so, then i'll let you know most people like their code not looking like math and more like code.

Comment: It eases coding and readability for me. There a lot of situations in which post- and prefix operators like this could become handy. It is nothing I absolutely require, but it would be a nice thing to have. Plus I gain knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me first say that I don't think this is a good idea. It's much more trouble than it's worth. But here goes:

```
prefix operator |
postfix operator |

prefix func | <T: Comparable & SignedNumeric>(f: () -> T) -> T {
    return f()
}

postfix func | <T: Comparable & SignedNumeric>(n: T) -> () -> T {
    return { abs(n) }
}


|42| // returns 42
|(-42)| // returns 42
```

The idea is that the postfix operator returns a function that is then used as the argument to the prefix operator, which then returns the end result. I originally had it the other way around (the prefix operator returning the function), but the compiler did not like that – it seems the postfix operator has a higher precedence.

The advantage of returning a function is that `|42` doesn't compile (because the argument types don't match) and while `42|` compiles, you will get an error as soon as you use it in a computation because of a type mismatch.

If you use this with literals, you still have to parenthesize negative numbers because Swift can't parse two consecutive prefix operators. I also haven't tested this very much, there may be other edge cases where it doesn't compile.